# Is it possible to group rows programmatically in KQL?

Tags: multiple-columns, settings, kql, group

Is it possible to group rows programmatically in KQL?

I know that I can run a query in KQL. And after that go to the right hand Columns settings, drag a column name to the Row Groups and group my rows this way.

Is there a way to do the same operation programmatically while writing a query? I searched for it in documentation and found nothing. Does it mean it is possible to group rows in KQL only manually?